# How can I add my custom type converters to SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Config my custom type converters by using (Spring 4.x)XML properties like this.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="factoryBean" />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" id="factoryBean" >
   <property name="converters">
     <list>
      <bean class="com.mvc.convertor.MyConvertor" />
     </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

MyConvertor implements **org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter**.
And how can I config my custom type converters by using SpringBoot.I have tried many methods but failed.Hope any one can help me to resolve.Thanks!

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration)? Just expose `MyConverter` as a bean and it will be picked up automatically

Answer (score 0):

As Stephane Nicoll pointed out spring boot should automatically pick up any converters registered as bean configuration in your application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        HttpMessageConverter<?> additional = ...
        HttpMessageConverter<?> another = ...
        return new HttpMessageConverters(additional, another);
    }

}
```

Comment: I know that HttpMessageConverters can be registered as bean configuration,but here my converter implements org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter which is type converter.I can not find any way to register type converter.T _ T

Comment: @zjcscut if you are writting custom message converters you should do by implementing HttpMessageConverter http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html. By other means spring will not be able understand and process your converters